# constant monitoring of answers on a port given

Tags: 10.04

I do need a tool that would work just like `ping`, but that shows me response on a given port.

I do know about `telnet` and `nmap`, but they give me only one result, not a constant loop, with which I could see changes over time.

is there anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The netcat utility will do exactly what you are looking for:

```
$ nc -lk 1234
```

The `-l` option will start netcat listening on a port. The `-k` option forces it to keep listening for new connections.

Netcat should be installed on your system by default; it is part of ubuntu-minimal. If not, you can install it with `apt-get install netcat-openbsd`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do that with **netcat** (command : `nc`)

You could do like the following example (which can be found in **netcat** manpage !):

```
$ echo "QUIT" | nc <yourhost> 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
Protocol mismatch.
$ # prompt returned here
```

You can specify a connection/idle timeout with `-w` flag. (see the manpage).

This example connects to the given port (here 22/SSH), read from it then send the string "QUIT". Note that "QUIT" string is arbitrary, depending on the expected protocol: with the example above it could be any string - the SSH server would terminate the connection.